# How to model users & permissions in EA?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I wonder how can I model relations between users and functions. I have 12 different actors in the system. On the other hand, there are 120 unique functions (not use cases) I can assign to users.

Does EA provide any matrix I can define connections between users and functions? Which type of diagram should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relationship matrix for this. You could write your own, but that's not trivial (though possible). What you could do is to create associations between actors and class operations (which is what I think you mean by functions) and issue the context menu near the class:

[image]

`Link to Element Feature` opens a menu where you choose `Operation` and select the appropriate operation:

[image]

This finally results in this:

[image]

You can attach more than one association this way. Note that the quick linker does not offer `Association` so you need to choose it from the context menu or the toolbox.

Comment: While technically you're right, I doubt this kind of representation would be clear to read. Moreover your approach does not address granting access per user

Comment: In this approach, an Actor is a role, I guess. @Ister, at the end, to code the operation access you should get this information. So why not using a matrix in EA ? You can model that without showing it on schema. no ?

Comment: @granier You can not use the "Link to.."  feature in the matrix.

Comment: @Kilian, in this case the remark of Ister may make sense, 12 roles, 120 functions ... Even with dedicated schemas it will be hard to maintain. I am not familiar with matrix feature of EA, but I would use an excel sheet (which sould not be different than a matrix) to maintain this rights information. But this is a choice.

Comment: @Ister I guess it depends. I rarely use that feature, but the OP seems to be ok with it.

Comment: @Kilian, just to know, this `Link element to feature` creates an UML association in the model or something else ?

Comment: Well, it's an EA feature that adorns a link. (BTW: you don't need to @ if you are commenting in a post of mine.)